# why a slight difference between the composition of an image (png format) after displaying it using drawImage?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, the "img" file is an image created with Gimp.
It contains a color pixel :
**rgba=176 99 234 167.**

When I display it in a context and then retrieve its composition
with getImageData, there is a small difference in the RGBA values...why?
**GetImageData =>  177,99,235,167**

The Browser is Firefox Version 101

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 1;
canvas.width = 1;

var img = new Image();

img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
//  rgba = 176 99 234 167

img.onload = function() {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
  console.log(imgData);
  console.log("this is not 176 99 234 167");
}
```

**updated June 20 :** My output with Firefox :
[image: My output with Firefox]

**updated June 19 :** maybe the explanation of the problem is in this link.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html

> **NOTE**
> *Due to the lossy nature of converting between color spaces and converting to and from premultiplied alpha color values, pixels that
> have just been set using putImageData(), and are not completely
> opaque, might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different
> values.*

Comment: [Worksforme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ5dD.png). What output are you getting?

Comment: Btw there's a lot [more data](https://www.nayuki.io/page/png-file-chunk-inspector) in that png file than the single pixel. Maybe has something to do with it? What browser do you use to render the canvas?

Comment: @Bergi, the browser is Firefox

Comment: Seems to be a Firefox thing, maybe about to how it handles sRGB colour space. It does not seem to occur on Chrome. Related?: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867594

Comment: @Berthur Can you make that an answer

Comment: @Bergi It's a bit vague :D But ok, in absence of more specific answers

Comment: @Bergi I just added my output

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the link about the png format! some time ago I had looked for clear explanations of this format without ever finding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in practice you cannot assume that the colour you read back has the same RGB values as the original PNG. Some browsers seem to keep it (Chrome) while some don't necessarily do so (Firefox).

It seems to be due to colour space conversions (sRGB). See e.g. this discussion: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867594

On Firefox, I get `(164, 102, 225, 167)`, which is different both to the original values and to your output, so it is indeed device dependent.

Comment: No, Chrome does not produce the result identical to bitmap values either.